# Probability in a Dice Game

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

By the following problem:

> Two players, $A$ and $B$, play a game where they, one after another, throw two dices. The first one to get a sum of $A$ wins the game. Let player $A$ be the one to play first. What is the probability that player $B$ wins the game?

I first thought that I should think of finite repetitions, say 10 or 100 and then count the probabilties and derive the formula, since the events are independent.

But then I realised I did not know how to do that for a very large amount of repetitions *(so many such that $n\to \infty $, where $n$ the number of repetitions)*. I then thought perhaps I should try to find the probability that A wins and take the complement of that. But, to be honest I am kind of lost.

My last guess is that it perhaps should be a Poisson experiment?

Any ideas are most welcome! Thank you!

Comment: Can you calculate the probability of winning in the $n$-th round?

Comment: A sum of $A$? Was a specific number intended? What is the connection with the name of one of the players?

Comment: Thank you guys I found a dublicate, it is exactly the same problem.